# How to pass nested parameter in Rest request through SoapUI

Tags: php, json, rest

I am new to Rest and i am making test cases in SoapUI. I have to pass json object as a parameter. I have made one test case for login successfully. Now i have to make test case to make a group. In this request the post parameters are nested. I tried to send it by writing json object in mediatype in soapui, but failed to do it. I can show you the request  how i actually want to send parameters.

```
"post":{
      "group":{"name":"Seniors"},
      "token":"{81A9B0D9-CA0E-E70F-ADFF-116EE7A1A980}"
 }
```

I have successfully send the login request that is as follow.

```
"post":{
"password":"jawad123",
"username":"jawad@gmail.com"
}
```

Can anybody help me that how can i send parameter nested as given above?

Answer (score 0):

In SoapUI version 5.2.1, there is an option "application/json" under "Media Type" select options. Just select that and give the nested JSON that needs to be sent as parameter in the text field below. In your case, it should be -

```
{
      "group":{"name":"Seniors"},
      "token":"{81A9B0D9-CA0E-E70F-ADFF-116EE7A1A980}"
}
```

Submit request and you should get the results.